# Computed Column Operand type clash on Date Column When Checking For Null

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, table, computed-column

This error is generated when trying to create a table with a computed column from a `Date` field.

> Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date

If I comment out the computed column it works.

```
[DateInActive][Date] NULL,             -- Date origination
[IsValid] AS (IsNull(DateInActive, 1)) -- Failure here
```

The thought on `IsValid` is to simply return a `bit` of on|off for this field to signify that no *in-active* date has been reported and if so, it is valid.

The column will ultimately be passed on to JSON in a `For JSON` output as a `is-a` field for usage outside SQL.

---

**Full SQL**

```
CREATE TABLE [history].[PhoneBook](
    [PhoneBookId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PersonId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PhoneId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DateActive][Date] NOT NULL,
    [DateInActive][Date] NULL,
    [IsValid] AS (IsNull(DateInActive, 1))
 CONSTRAINT [PK_PhoneBook_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PersonId] ASC,
    [PhoneId] ASC

)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
       ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [`ISNULL` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql) the returned data type is the same type as the check expression, which is data type `date` in this case. The `ISNULL` expression fails because the integer literal 1 cannot be implicitly converted to date.

To return a bit indicating whether or not the date column is `NULL`, you could instead use a CASE expression:

```
CREATE TABLE [history].[PhoneBook](
    [PhoneBookId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PersonId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PhoneId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DateActive][Date] NOT NULL,
    [DateInActive][Date] NULL,
    [IsValid] AS CASE WHEN DateInActive IS NULL THEN CAST(0 AS BIT) ELSE CAST(1 AS bit) END
 CONSTRAINT [PK_PhoneBook_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PersonId] ASC,
    [PhoneId] ASC

)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
       ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```